# Henstock-Kurzweil integral of $f(x)=n$ for $x=1/n$ (and zero otherwise)

Tags: integration, gauge-integral

I need to prove that the function
$$
  f(x)
= \begin{cases}
  n &   x=1/n \\
  0 & \text{ otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
$$
defined on $[0,1]$ is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable.

I've tried to define $A={1/k}$  ($k=1,\ldots, \infty$)
and 
$$
  \delta(x)
= \begin{cases}
  \epsilon/(4k2^k) & x \text{ at } A; \\
  0    & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
$$
but I am not sure it's OK.

that you.

Comment: Do you mean to write $A = \{ 1/k \mid k = 1,\ldots,\infty\} $? And is $x$ at $A$ supposed to mean $x \in A$?

Comment: yes, something like dirichlet proof

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $A=\{\frac{1}{k}∣k=1,…,\infty\}$ and

$
\delta (x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\epsilon\cdot x}{2^n},  & \text{if $x\in A$ } \\
1, & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases} 
$

so if $(P,Y)$ is tagged partition and $P$ is $\delta$-fine so

$
I(f,P,Y)\le \sum_{m=1}^\infty{f(1/m)\cdot\delta (1/m)}
$
because the function is not negative

$
I(f,P,Y)\le \sum_{m=1}^\infty{f(1/m)\cdot\delta (1/m)}=
\sum_{m=1}^\infty{m\cdot\epsilon\cdot (1/m)/2^n}=
\sum_{m=1}^\infty{\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}}=\epsilon
$

so the function is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable and $\int_0^1{f(x)} dx=0$